# VB.NET 2008: How to create a new sub or function in code?

Tags: vb.net

Hi
I remember that C# editor has a powerful option that when we are developing in code and type a new method (operation) name for a class, we can create its body by clicking on ALT+Shift+F10 and immediately, it will be created for it's own class.

what about in VB.NET 2008 editor?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not vb user, but try CTRL+. alternative.